# How to clean xxx.<number>.vrb with latexmk

Tags: beamer, latexmk

The latex class beamer in a file `xxx.tex` produces `xxx.vrb` files in conjunction with fragile frames.

As shown in the manual, also `xxx.<number>.vrb` can occur.

I ask myself (and above all the community): How can I clean these files using latexmk?

As far as I can see, there is no way to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
$clean_ext = '%R*.vrb';
```

to your `.latexmkrc` file

Comment: Ah no, that will not solve the problem with the numbers. 
I think to clean just xxx.vrb, where xxx is the jobname, 
I shall add ' %R.vrb' (note the blank also).

Comment: @user2609605 I added a wildcard so that it also captures the frames with labels

Comment: Really it works.. almost perfect.. but also xxx.bla.vrb would be removed. 
Is there a way to restrict to numbers instead of bla?

Comment: @user2609605 Under which scenario would a `xxx.bla.vrb` be created?

Comment: none, I said *would*, I just wonder whether there are regular expressions, but seemingly no.
Thank you, I think my question is answered.